# Woocommerce Product Permalink & View media attachment

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, permalinks

Trying to edit a featured product image in media->library and clicking on "view attachment page", I get a 404 code error, page not found.

I noticed that this happen only with product content type. No problem with post or pages attachment view.

In my case I have permalink settings configured like this:

**Common Settings:** Month and name

**Optional:** Product category base: product-category | Product tag base: product-tag

**Product permalink base**: Custom base: /solutions/%product_cat%

With the config above, view attachment page url is structured like follow and return the 404 error:

```
sitename/solutions/product-category/single-product-page/single-product-featured-image‎
```

Note: the problem "disappear" if you set default permalink in common settings..(!?)

Additionally, despite that no reference made in sitemaps for these urls (I use WordPress SEO by Yoast), google bot index the same and report of course the problem as page/url not found.

Configuration: woocommerce 2.1.5 + WP 3.8.1

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

check did you've set those Settings in Permalinks properly, might help or not.

Product category base: product-category
Product tag base: product-tag
Product attribute base: /attribute-name/attribute